# Php error Notice:Undefined offset:255715

Tags: symfony

hello I'm working  on a symfony2 project , and when I'm trying to create associative array  this issue happend => Notice: Undefined offset :25715

My code editor  alert me that the error come from when I'am create my assoiative array $Tableau_comptes_dependants
here is code

```
foreach ($tableau_compte_fictifs as $tableau_compte_fictif) {
    $Tableau_id_compte_fictifs[] = $tableau_compte_fictif["id"];
}// this array content two value 25715 and 31170                      

foreach ($Tableau_id_compte_fictifs as $Tableau_id_compte_fictif) {

       $Mes_comptes_reels_dependants = $mes_comptesRepo-
           >all_client_compte_dependant($Tableau_id_compte_fictif);

    if (count($Mes_comptes_reels_dependants) > 0) {

    foreach ($Mes_comptes_reels_dependants as 
                $Mes_comptes_reels_dependant) 
    {
      if (!in_array($Mes_comptes_reels_dependant,
                $Tableau_comptes_dependants[$Tableau_id_compte_fictif]))
      {
                $Tableau_comptes_dependants[$Tableau_id_compte_fictif[] =
                    $Mes_comptes_reels_dependant;
      }
    }
}
}
return new JsonResponse(
    array(
        'code' => 200,
        'result' => true,
        'comptes' => $Tableau_id_compte_fictifs,
    )
);
```

please let me know what I'am doing wrong

Comment: Please indent the code properly to easy read. Thanks

Comment: this should be a syntax error: `$Tableau_comptes_dependants[$Tableau_id_compte_fictif[]`

Answer (score 0):

The notice is generated from your call to `in_array`:

```
if (!in_array($Mes_comptes_reels_dependant,
                $Tableau_comptes_dependants[$Tableau_id_compte_fictif]))
```

You try to access your array on an index that does not exist, 25715, since this is the value of your variable which you pass between the square brackets.

You should check first, if an index exists with `isset`, before accessing it.

That said, I think your code has a design flaw if you run into problems like this. You should try to refactor it or talk with your co workers about how to simplify it. I must admit, that I, although I could, won't try solving this problem for you, since your variable names are basically unreadable.